# Sybase ASE run query from one DB on the other

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

I have 2 databases `DB` and `DB_ARCHIVE`.

My SPROC archives (inserts records from `DB` into `DB_ARCHIVE`) records.
My SPROC **resides** in `DB`, but inside the SPROC I need to run a count on the records in the tables in `DB_ARCHIVE`

This is where my issue arises. I can run:

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID("DB.dbo.TABLE_NAME"))
```

in `DB` to get the row counts, but if I do:

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID("DB_ARCHIVE.dbo.TABLE_NAME"))
```

I only get a row count of 0 (fails).

Would someone know how I could run this query command in the SPROC on the `DB_ARCHIVE` database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the right database_id.
Try this:

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT(DB_ID("DB_ARCHIVE"), OBJECT_ID("DB_ARCHIVE.dbo.TABLE_NAME"))
```